# SQL Server Rolling Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rank

I have a table of stock prices for different dates.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (MyDate DATE, Ticker VarChar(6), Price Decimal (6,2))

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES ('1/1/13' , 'ABC' , '100.00')
          ,('1/2/13' , 'ABC' , '101.50')  
          ,('1/3/13' , 'ABC' , '99.80')
          ,('1/4/13' , 'ABC' , '95.50')
          ,('1/5/13' , 'ABC' , '78.00')
          ,('1/1/13' , 'JKL' , '34.57')
          ,('1/2/13' , 'JKL' , '33.99')  
          ,('1/3/13' , 'JKL' , '31.85')
          ,('1/4/13' , 'JKL' , '30.11')
          ,('1/5/13' , 'JKL' , '45.00')
          ,('1/1/13' , 'XYZ' , '11.50')
          ,('1/2/13' , 'XYZ' , '12.10')  
          ,('1/3/13' , 'XYZ' , '17.15')
          ,('1/4/13' , 'XYZ' , '14.10')
          ,('1/5/13' , 'XYZ' , '15.55')
```

I want to calculate the running 3-day rank (based on today and the two prior days) for each Ticker and for each date.

I can create a static rank, but cannot produce a dynamic rolling rank.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY Price DESC) AS Rank_3d
FROM 
    @table
ORDER BY 
    Ticker ASC, MyDate DESC
```

Output:

```
MyDate  Ticker  PRICE   Rank_3d
-------------------------------
2013-01-05  ABC 78.00   5
2013-01-04  ABC 95.50   4
2013-01-03  ABC 99.80   3
2013-01-02  ABC 101.50  1
2013-01-01  ABC 100.00  2
2013-01-05  JKL 45.00   1
2013-01-04  JKL 30.11   5
2013-01-03  JKL 31.85   4
2013-01-02  JKL 33.99   3
2013-01-01  JKL 34.57   2
2013-01-05  XYZ 15.55   2
2013-01-04  XYZ 14.10   3
2013-01-03  XYZ 17.15   1
2013-01-02  XYZ 12.10   4
2013-01-01  XYZ 11.50   5
```

My output should look like this:

```
MyDate     Ticker    Price    Rank_3d
-------------------------------------
1/3/13     ABC       99.80    3
1/4/13     ABC       95.50    3
1/5/13     ABC       78.00    3
1/3/13     JKL       31.85    3
1/4/13     JKL       30.11    3
1/5/13     JKL       45.00    1
1/3/13     XYZ       17.15    1
1/4/13     XYZ       14.10    2
1/5/13     XYZ       15.55    2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "simple" way to do this with the ranking functions.

For your particular problem, it is not that hard to do with `lag()`.  The logic is a bit tricky for the first two days (the missing values) and when there are ties.  But here is one approach:

```
select t.*,
       (case when price = max(price) over (partition by ticker order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
             then 1
             when price = min(price) over (partition by ticker order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
             then 3
             else 2
        end) as rank_3day
from @table t;
```

Even with `apply` the logic is tricky:

```
select t.*, t2.rank
from @table t cross apply
     (select count(*) as rank
      from (select top (3) t2.*
            from @table t2
            where t2.date <= t.date
            order by t2
           ) t2
      where t2.price >= t.price
     ) t2
```

Comment: I'm really interested in creating rankings over longer lookback periods such as 60days.  Should I be thiking about loops to do this?

Comment: @Coding_Newbie . . . Just use `cross apply`.